# What is the difference between starring and pinning in Slack?

Tags: slack

What is the difference between pinning a message and starring a message (other than how the UI makes the appropriate buttons available)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to slack:

> Stars are a way to mark an item in Slack as important. You can star
>   channels or direct messages to move them to the top of your left
>   sidebar, or star messages so you can easily come back to them later.
>
> Any items you star are marked only for you. To mark something as
>   important for everyone on your team, try pinning the item to a
>   channel.

And for pins:

> Important messages and files can be pinned to the details pane in any
>   channel or direct message, including group messages, for easy
>   reference.
>
> A message will appear in the channel or DM letting others know you’ve
>   pinned an item. Your pinned item will be shown in the details pane,
>   which you can open by clicking the pin icon.
>
> Note: A maximum of 100 messages or files can be pinned to any one
>   channel or direct message at a time.

SO, basically, starring is *just for you*, and pins are *public/communal*.
Pinning things also adds it to the channel details for easy access to everyone.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! That is a great answer. I added some formatting to it to make it easier to read.